# Elasticsearch search with multi fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

How can i create body for elasticsearch like this

```
select * from table where full_name like '%q%' or address like '%q%' or description like '%q%' order by full_name , description , address
```

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself?

Comment: yes, but in multi_match have only phrase_prefix but i need someting like wildcard

Comment: I think you should read a bit more about full text search.

Comment: And it's better to add to your question what you already tried and why it didn't work (in case you know).

Comment: I just know something like analyzer but it is difficult to understand about it and now I already know prefix so I think maybe have the way to get both (pre and post)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A wildcard query can be very expensive, especially if you search in several fields. The right way to do this is by using an [`nGram` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenfilter.html) on the fields you want to search only a part of.

First you create an index like below with a custom analyzer that will slice and dice your fields into searchable tokens:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tests -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "substring_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "substring"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "substring": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 15
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test": {
      "properties": {
        "full_name": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "substring_analyzer"
        },
        "address": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "substring_analyzer"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "substring_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then you can index a few docs:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tests/test/_bulk -d '
{"index":{"_id": 1}}
{"full_name": "Doe", "address": "1234 Quinn Street", "description": "Lovely guy"}
{"index":{"_id": 2}}
{"full_name": "Brennan", "address": "4567 Main Street", "description": "Not qualified"}
{"index":{"_id": 3}}
{"full_name": "Quantic", "address": "1234 Quinn Street", "description": "New friend"}
'
```

Finally, you can search with a query equivalent to your SQL query above and all three test documents will match:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/tests/test/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "full_name": "q"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "address": "q"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "description": "q"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. . .
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html
`

```
{
    "wildcard" : { "user" : "ki*y" }
}
```

`